# Installing Sonar in eclipse without network

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sonarqube, private-network

I am currently working on installing sonar into eclipse. The machienes I am installing them on, however, run on a private server. I cannot install from the eclipse marketplace. I was wondering how I can get the proper files needed to install the plug-in?

Answer (score 0):

Same answer I gave on the Eclipse forums:

One option for installing on machines without Internet access would be if the Sonar plugin developers provide an Update Site Archive (which can be used from Eclipse's Install New Software wizard). Looking at their [instructions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) it doesn't look like they do, but maybe you could reach out to them and ask for it. Producing an archive isn't much trouble if they're already publishing an update site (which it appears they are).

Another option exists, if you have at least one machine on that network that can install the plugin: share that machine's Eclipse installation folder on the network so other machines can see it, then use **File** > **Import** > **Install** > **From Existing Installation** to select the shared Eclipse folder where Sonar is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ticket created to provide a zipped update site for next version:
http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCLIPS-448